# Melhor forma para acessar componentes da activity - MVP

Tags: android, design-pattern

Estou utilizando o padrão MVP no meu projeto Android.

Em minha MainActivity tenho os seguintes componentes:

```
private Paciente paciente;
private EditText nome, cpf, cpfTutor, telefone;
private CheckBox checkbox;
```

logo depois tenho esse metodo que é iniciado quando se clica em um botão:

```
private void initPaciente() {
    paciente = new Paciente();

    paciente.setNome(nome.getText().toString());
    paciente.setCpfTitular(cpf.getText().toString());
    paciente.setCpfTutor(cpfTutor.getText().toString());
    paciente.setTelefone(telefone.getText().toString());
    paciente.setDataCadastro("27/01/2017");
    paciente.setStatus(status.getSelectedItem().toString().toLowerCase());
    paciente.setTimestamp(new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()).getTime());

    paciente.save;
}
```

Bom, se eu intendi bem o conceito do MVP esse tipo de acesso direto ao objeto paciente não é válido.

Como que eu acesso esses componentes `EditText nome, cpf, cpfTutor, telefone;` pelo Presenter?

Eu tentei acessar assim:

```
private PacienteActivity activity = (PacienteActivity) getContext();
Paciente paciente = new Paciente();
paciente.setNome(activity.nome.getText().toString());
// ...
```

Mas desse modo tenho que deixar os atributos como public (que não acho bacana), ou criar um monte de geters que vão poluir meu codigo.

Comment: eu estudei pelo blog do Thiengo: http://www.thiengo.com.br/mvp-android, e tem um vídeo no YT: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WRGqmqZwEcQ, também dele, que explica melhor como utilizar esses conceitos.

Comment: Se está preocupado em seguir padrões e "boas práticas", reveja o facto de Paciente ser responsável por se gravar a si próprio.

Comment: Sim, isso no exemplo acima eu tinha antes de seguir os padrões. Hoje o objeto é responsável por apenas controlar seus dados, quem o persiste agora é a Model. Mas de qualquer forma, muito obrigado pela dica.

Answer (score 2):

Dentro do padrão MVP (`Model-View-Presenter`), a construção do objeto `Paciente` deve ser feita dentro do seu `Presenter` e sua `View` (seja ela `Activity` ou `Fragment`) fica responsável apenas por *ceder as informações* para seu `Presenter`.

Primeiro, você precisa criar um *contrato* (`interface`) entre seu `Presenter` e `View`:

```
public interface PacienteView {
    String getNome();
    String getCpfTitular(); 
    ...
}
```

E a implemente dentro de sua `View`:

```
public class PacienteFragment implements PacienteView {

    @Override
    void getNome() {
        return nome.getText().toString();
    }

    @Override
    void getCpfTitular() {
        return cpf.getText().toString();
    }

    ...
}
```

A parte "confusa" vem agora: seu `Presenter` precisa acessar essas informações de alguma maneira. Você tem várias opções de fazer isso, mas aproveitando que no [Java nós conseguimos ter uma instância de uma interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/interfaceAsType.html), precisamos de uma instancia nossa interface `PacienteView` com nosso `Presenter`, para assim podemos construir o objeto `Paciente`:

```
public class PacientePresenter {

    private PacienteView view;

    public void configuraPaciente() {
        Paciente paciente = new Paciente ();

        paciente.setNome(view.getNome());
        paciente.setCpfTitular(view.getCpfTitular());
        ...
    }
}
```

Agora, dentro da nossa `View`, precisamos atrelar a intância `view` (instanciada acima) ao nosso `Presenter`. Para fazer isso, é bem tranquilo. É algo como um `setOnClickListener(this)` que você deve estar acostumado a utilizar:

```
public class PacientePresenter {

    private PacienteView view;

    public void setView(PacienteView view) {
        this.view = view;
    }
}

...

public class PacienteFragment implements PacienteView {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        presenter = new SubscriptionsPresenter();

        presenter.setView(this);
    }
}
```

Pronto! Dessa maneira seu `Presenter` irá ter a instância da `View` e você pode adicionar o que for preciso nos métodos. Agora, para salvar seu objeto `Paciente`, ficaria algo como:

```
public class PacienteFragment implements PacienteView {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        presenter = new SubscriptionsPresenter();

        presenter.setView(this);
    }

    ...

    private void initPaciente() {
        presenter.configuraPaciente();
    }
}
```

Comment: E quando eu for receber dados de um servidor, por exemplo? É o presenter que deverá fazer a request?

Comment: @Mr_Anderson O `Presenter` é responsável por providenciar as informações para a `View`. Nesse caso, o `Presenter` deve trabalhar em conjunto com outros patterns (como `Client` ou `Repository`) para realizar essas requisições.